# Is it possible to install the Win8 TTS voices, David, Hazel, Zira onto Win7 / XP?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, text-to-speech

I googled, but did not find a definitive answer.

Windows 8 comes with David, Zira and Hazel.

Windows 7 comes with Anna.

Is it possible to install the new voices on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no redistributable versions of the Windows 8 TTS voices.